# Spring social google example fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-social, spring-oauth2, spring-social-google

I've cloned [spring social google example](https://github.com/spring-social/spring-social-google-example). Tried it start with specified google account following `README.md` but it unfortunately started with fails. I used command:

```
mvn tomcat7:run -Dgoogle.clientId=MY_APP_CLIENT_ID -Dgoogle.clientSecret=MY_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
```

If I try http://localhost:8080/, I'll get server exception:

```
Jul 26, 2017 1:48:57 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:232)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1329)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromVariantTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1385)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeArgumentsFromSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1172)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getTypeFromTypeSignature(LookupEnvironment.java:1334)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:550)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.createMethods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:630)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:688)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:296)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getPackage(Scope.java:2376)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedQualifiedTypeReference.internalResolveLeafType
```

...

```
Jul 26, 2017 1:48:57 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1 findType
SEVERE: Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException

at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:232)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2469)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1006)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:459)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
```

...

```
Jul 26, 2017 1:48:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
```

---

I expected that shared spring's projects work perfectly, and I believe it works. ...but who knows maybe I do something wrong. May be I need create special project account to use `MY_APP_CLIENT_ID` and `MY_APP_CLIENT_SECRET`, may be I need special server configuration or network tooling...

Comment: Runs with JDK7. This error pops up using JDK8.